# lodash object to array

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, lodash

I am using lodash to find multiple Objects in an Array.

Here's my current Array when I output `JSON.stringify(userList)`:

```
[
   {"Id":1,"Username":"Usr1","Licenses":["IN","OH"]},
   {"Id":2,"Username":"Usr2","Licenses":["IN","FL"]},
   {"Id":3,"Username":"Usr3","Licenses":["MI"]}
]
```

I want to find all Loan Officers who have a `License` in Indiana.

I am using the lodash library and add the following line of code:

```
var result = _.find(userList, function (o) { return ~o.Licenses.indexOf(state);});
```

However, this would only return 1 Object, `"Id":2` and **NOT BOTH** Users with Licneses in Indiana.

**How can I have `_.find()` return me ALL Users with a License in "IN"? Perhaps I need to use a different lodash method and thats fine with me.**

Also, if only 1 User is returned back to me, like a User with a Florida license, I need it to return the result as an Array, just like so:

```
[
   {"Id":2,"Username":"Usr2","Licenses":["IN","FL"]}
]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You *can't* use `_.find` to do what you want.  Read the documentation: https://lodash.com/docs#find where it says `_.find` "Iterates over elements of collection, returning the *first* element"

Answer (score 1):

you can use _.filter - which returns all matched items

Answer (score 0):

lodash's method [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) is a way to go:

> Iterates over elements of collection, returning an array of all elements predicate returns truthy for.

`_.find` returns only first matched element

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows. It will get you all objects with searched state. You can search for multiple states as well.

```js
myData = [
          {"Id":1,"Username":"Usr1","Licenses":["IN","OH"]},
          {"Id":2,"Username":"Usr2","Licenses":["IN","FL"]},
          {"Id":3,"Username":"Usr3","Licenses":["MI"]}
         ],
getAll = (...sts) => myData.reduce((p,o) => sts.some( s => o.Licenses.includes(s)) ? p.concat(o) : p ,[]);

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(getAll("IN"),null,2) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array's` `filter` function without using `lodash`

So one liner would be

```
var state = 'IN';
var test = [
   {"Id":1,"Username":"Usr1","Licenses":["IN","OH"]},
   {"Id":2,"Username":"Usr2","Licenses":["IN","FL"]},
   {"Id":3,"Username":"Usr3","Licenses":["MI"]}
]

test.filter(x=>x.Licenses.includes(state))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to do it using chain, filter and includes

```js
var users = [
   {"Id":1,"Username":"Usr1","Licenses":["IN","OH"]},
   {"Id":2,"Username":"Usr2","Licenses":["IN","FL"]},
   {"Id":3,"Username":"Usr3","Licenses":["MI"]}
];

var ret = _.chain(users).filter(function(o){
         return _.includes(o.Licenses,'IN');
    }).value();

console.log(ret);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.12.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```